# Own classloader for springframework TaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring, classloader, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job that run on single JVM.

Every taskitem processing invoked by `org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor#execute`

Application has a bottleneck in parallel processing: every taskitem invoke synchronized method from 3-party lib.

```
protected synchronized boolean doFetch(java.lang.String currencyCheckValue, boolean cachePersistently, boolean useSharedCacheIgnored, java.lang.Object[] extendedArgs) throws com.documentum.fc.common.DfException { /* compiled code */ }
```

Is it possible to use `TaskExecutor` implementation, that run task in own classloader, to avoid synchronized method invocation bottleneck?

Can you suggest such implementations?

Comment: Seems, it'll be implemented in Spring batch 3.0.0 https://jira.springsource.org/browse/BATCH-2071

Comment: The referenced issue is not the same as what is being asked.  BATCH-2071 is the implementation of section 10.5 of JSR-352 which allows a batch artifact to be configured by placing the class name in the ref attribute instead of the name.